# How to charge MacBook Pro quickly from an iMac?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, thunderbolt, charging

I am charging a MacBook Pro using a Thunderbolt 3 cable plugged into an iMac. This charging speed is exceptionally slow. The image shows 5+ hours to charge the laptop.

[image]

I am using:

- 2018 MacBook Pro 13" with Touch Bar
- 2017 Retino 4K 21.5-inch iMac
- Apple Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) Cable (0.8m)

This cable costs $39 retail. At this price I am expecting better performance for charging than what I'm getting here. How could I diagnose this issue?

Comment: Why not just charge it with the charger it came with!

Comment: I didn't want to schlep that to the office each day

Comment: Then buy an extra charger and leave it at the office.

Comment: I don't want to crowd my desk with an extra charger. "The Apple Way™" is surely to have less wires.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> This cable costs $39 retail. At this price I am expecting better
>   performance for charging than what I'm getting here. How could I
>   diagnose this issue?

**There's nothing to diagnose because everything is operating as it should.**

The problem is not the cable (it's irrelevant, actually) nor the iMac as it's only capable of delivering up to 15W of power via the Thunderbolt 3 ports. From [Apple's Support Document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204392).

> Your iMac also has two Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports....Thunderbolt 3 also supports USB 3.1 Gen 2 connectivity at up to 10Gbps, and **can supply 15W of power per port** to external devices.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

[Your MacBook Pro requires a 61W charger](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700) so, in essence, you're using a charger that can only supply a quarter (25%) of what you're MacBook Pro requires.  Therefore, the long charging time is accurate and to be expected.

Bottom line - use the charger that came with your MacBook Pro.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken no. You want each thunderbolt 3 port to have the capability to charge a laptop!? That’s such a bizarre edge case. Just buy a 60W charger.

Comment: Yes, I want my iMac to at least charge an iPad Pro at full speed. iPad Pro charger is 18W.

Comment: The power output of the iMac being 15W is about 84% of the required power for the iPad pro.  It will charge "fairly quickly" but not at the maximum rate.  Keep in mind that nowhere in the Tech Specs for the iMac does Apple say they're "charging ports."

Comment: @WilliamEntriken, If you got your way, then others would gripe, "I wish my iMac was thinner and lighter."

Comment: @GlenYates: I looked up the specs. The iMac 5K has the highest power consumption of all iMacs, at 217W with full CPU load. The iMac has 6 USB ports (4 Type A, 2 Type C). Type A can deliver up to 7,5W using USB-BC. Type C can deliver up to 100W using USB-PD. So, the USB ports can deliver up to 230W in total, which is more than the entire iMac uses itself. This means, what the OP wants would require a power supply that can deliver twice the power, which roughly means it is twice as big and twice as heavy. The power supply is a major contributor to the iMac's weight after the display.

Comment: … An iMac that can deliver full charging via its USB ports would not be heavier and thicker, it would be *significantly* heavier and thicker. (I ignored the problem that the power supply would likely also be warmer, for example. So, you also need more cooling.)

Comment: @Tim Not a bizarre edge case.  This will be the powersupply of the future.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen you’re saying that charging a 60W laptop from an iMac is something most iMac users do?! And I highly doubt it will be the power supply of the future. We’re heading towards better, not worse, power consumption.

Comment: @Tim No, but in the coming years this is what we will see more and more.  USB-C will replace the chargers and even if you are consuming power better, you still need power.

Answer (score 8):

[According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207097) the best way to charge your MacBook Pro is with the included AC adapter. They don't mention plugging into an iMac specifically, but based on your report of a long predicted charging time, I'm going to guess that iMacs don't put out as much energy over thunderbolt as the AC adapter.

[According to this page on the Thunderbolt 3 Cable](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208368), it is definitely  the iMac's power output, not the cable that is limiting the charging speed.